# In C, how to disable optimization in the makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile structure

```
# Default optimization level
O ?= 2

TESTS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(sort $(wildcard test[0-9][0-9][0-9].c)))

all: $(TESTS) hhtest

-include build/rules.mk
LIBS = -lm

%.o: %.c $(BUILDSTAMP)
$(call run,$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -O$(O) $(DEPCFLAGS) -o $@ -c,COMPILE,$<)

test%: test%.o m61.o
$(call run,$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS),LINK $@)

hhtest: hhtest.o m61.o
$(call run,$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS),LINK $@)
```

And when I debugging I have `<optimized out>` value:

```
print ptr
<optimized out>
```

How to disable that issue?

Comment: Having a single-letter variable name is really not very friendly. Having that letter be a a capital `O` is even less so. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be structured in such a way (i.e. you pass `-O$(O)` to cc) that you should be able to say:

```
O ?= 0
```

Instead of `O ?= 2`.